# Makefile ifndef variable in target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Please believe me: I searched and tested a lot... but I don't get whats wrong here:

```
VERSION := 123

all:
    ifndef VERSION
        $(error VERSION not set)
    else
        $(info Start deploy $(VERSION))
    endif
```

outputs `VERSION not set`

what I really wanted was to call make like `VERSION=1.2.3 make` but not even setting the variable in the Makefile worked

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

For me it outputs `Start deploy 123`.

Note that `ifndef` and `$(error)` and `$(info)` are part of makefile syntax, not the recipe syntax belonging to `all` target. So, your code is equivalent to:

```
VERSION := 123
ifndef VERSION
$(error VERSION not set)
else
$(info Start deploy $(VERSION))
endif
```

Comment: thanks, now I'm even more puzzled. On my ubutnu server (GNU make 4.1) it works too, on my mac (GNU make 3.81 and brew GNU make 4.2) it doesn't work

Your clarification about "not belongig to all" is good for me, since i originally wanted these tests to be run "before" all, but this didn't seem to work either

Comment: ok.... figured it out finally and thanks to the input by @maxim-egorushkin 
Do not use indentation for the if-text

Comment: @huehnerhose make-3.81 is decade old. Use the latest version.

Comment: GNU make (as with all GNU utilities) changed its license to GPLv3.  Apple has a long-standing history of never using anything under GPLv3.  That's why the versions of bash, GNU make, and other GNU utilities provided with MacOS are so ancient, and they will never be updated.  You'll have to download/install it yourself (from brew or via source) rather than using what comes with MacOS if you want a newer version.

Comment: Just for clarification: you can use "indentation".  What you can't do is indent using a TAB character, if the line appears in a rule context.  If you do that then the indented lines are considered part of the recipe for the rule and won't be run until/unless the recipe is invoked.  Basically in Makefiles, TAB indentation is very special and should never be used anywhere other than inside recipes.  Indenting with spaces is completely innocuous and not special at all.